# Xpath Scraping Developer Website from Google Play

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm new to xpath and **scraping** pages. I need to extract a link to the developer website from google play app page (Developer -> Visit Website) by using importxml function in google sheets. Tried several approaches, didn't work:

1. Started with //main
   importxml(link; "//main/c-wiz[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div//div[9]/div/span/div/span/div/@href")
   Full xpath from Developer Console
2. importxml(link; "//div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div/main/c-wiz[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[9]/span/div/span/div[1]/a/@href")

Before **scraping** google play page, I had similar task for AppStore and came up with following formula that didn't work on Google Play: importxml(link; "//section[contains(@class,'section--link-list')]/ul/li[1]/a/@href")

For me the main issue now that the path to the website link is correct in the first two cases, but I cannot get any link at all. Can you please advice me how to **scrape** it correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share the link. Probably the content is generated by JavaScript that `IMPORTXML` cannot get the content.

Comment: Have a look here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun and check if the content is added dynamically.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' and 'scrapping' are about throwing stuff away like rubbish :-(

Comment: ok, thank you! didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'url:' 
    and Col1 ends with '}'", 0), """(.*)""")
```

[image]

[image]